# Guide legend title position on mapping color and fill in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'am trying to position the legends (and their titles) of colors and fill mappings. But the continuous legend turns into what looks like a discrete one.

Here is a toy example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geobr)
library(viridis)

mun <- geobr::read_municipality(showProgress = FALSE, simplified = TRUE) |> 
       mutate(code_state = as.numeric(code_state))
```

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data = mun,
            mapping = aes(geometry = geom,
                          fill = code_state,
                          colour = code_state)) +
    viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name = "Some title") +
    viridis::scale_color_viridis() +  
    theme_bw() +  
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data = mun,
            mapping = aes(geometry = geom,
                          fill = code_state,
                          colour = code_state)) +
    viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name = "Some title") +
    viridis::scale_color_viridis() +  
    theme_bw() +  
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                                title.hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

How to put the legend on the bottom, the title of the legend on the top of the legend and keep the continuous color pallete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default legend for a continuous fill or color scale is `guide="colorbar"`, i.e. use `guide_colorbar` instead of `guide_legend`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(geobr)
#> Warning: package 'geobr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Loading required namespace: sf
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

mun <- geobr::read_municipality(showProgress = FALSE, simplified = TRUE) |>
  mutate(code_state = as.numeric(code_state))
#> Using year 2010

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = mun,
    mapping = aes(
      geometry = geom,
      fill = code_state,
      colour = code_state
    )
  ) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name = "Some title") +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(
    title.position = "top",
    title.hjust = 0.5
  ),
  color = guide_colorbar(
    title.position = "top",
    title.hjust = 0.5
  )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I knew that it was something simple that I was missing! So, guide_legend can force a discrete legend, good to know!